# plpgsql function with conditional statement to access column name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a conditional statement in a plpgsql function what will filter out only the records I want through an if statement. I am just testing now, but here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  housenum character varying(30),
  prefix character varying(10),
  name character varying(100),
  type character varying(16)
)
```

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "geomCheck".getAllFoo() RETURNS SETOF 
addresses AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
        r addresses%rowtype;
    BEGIN
        FOR r IN SELECT * FROM addresses
        WHERE gid > 0
        LOOP
        if name = 'BRIE' then
         RETURN NEXT r;
        end if;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

But when I go to call the function I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT name = 'BRIE'
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT name = 'BRIE'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "geomCheck".getallfoo() line 8 at IF
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "name" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Context: PL/pgSQL function "geomCheck".getallfoo() line 8 at IF
```

How do I check if the `name = 'BRIE'` in the `if` statement?

Comment: @lad2025 that worked. If you want to add that I will give you credit.

Comment: You are aware that your function burns down to: `SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE gid > 0 AND name = 'BRIE';`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, I've just never used a conditional statement in plpgsql. I'm going to use this to create more complex logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix name with `r`:

```
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM addresses
    WHERE gid > 0
    LOOP
    if r.name = 'BRIE' then    -- instead of "name" => "r.name"
     RETURN NEXT r;
    end if;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
```